# Is 1 hour 35 minutes sufficient to connect flights at Muscat Airport?

Tags: tickets, airport-transfer, short-connections, muscat, oman-air

I am travelling from Cairo to Karachi using two Oman Air flights. The flights have transit time of one hour and 35 minutes time at Muscat Airport. Is this time is sufficient for transfer to catch the connecting flight to Karachi at Muscat Airport.

Comment: Standard question: Is this a single ticket or two separate tickets ? What's your nationality?

Comment: How does a question asking if 1h35m is enough time to do something get closed as a dup of a question asking if 2 hours is enough to do something?  If I asked "is 5 minutes enough" would that get closed as a dup of this too? (ie, the answer would be 'Yes, it is!")

Comment: You want my personal opinion? Questions asking if X amount of time is enough to transfer should all be formatted as "how long is the minimum time to connect".
Most of the current questions are pretty subjective and not answer completely the question (typically the question remains about the single or separate tickets). In that specific case, the answer to a 2-hour connection says "you'll have plenty of time" so it's likely that 1h35 should be "sufficient". And the same exact reasons will be stated.